# how to check if a port is blocked on a windows server

Tags: windows, networking

I have a windows server 2008 machine which has qlikview application installed and this application has stopped working from last week, the application services were stopped. I'm unable to start the services(services are configured with the local account). As part of troubleshooting, I checked netstat to verify if the application ports are opened. I could not see on the list a couple of application related ports( eg. 4799, 4750). How do I verify if the ports are open or blocked on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps 9originally from elsewhere but fits your situation)

Assuming that it's a TCP (rather than UDP) port that you're trying to use:

1.On the server itself, use netstat -an to check to see which ports are listening

2.From outside, just telnet host port (or telnet host:port on Unix systems) to see if the connection is refused, accepted, or timeouts

On that latter test, then in general:

- connection refused means that nothing is running on that port
- accepted means that something is running on that port
- timeout means that a firewall is blocking access

Comment: I did netstat -an but the required port is not displayed on the machine. What does this mean ? whether the port is not open or port is blocked.

Comment: It doesn't mean the port is blocked, just that there's nothing listening on it. If I have a webserver listening on port 80, netstat will show me something like "httpd.exe    80    tcp    LISTEN". If I stop the web service, then nothing will be shown for port 80, because nothing has bound to that port to listen for traffic.

Comment: so telnet in from outside to see what the result is that way you get open / closed etc.

Comment: If I telnet to the localhost and the connection is refused. I did not try telnet from outside because it may require to open the port on the firewall

Comment: telnet to the win server from a different machine in the network to check the win server firewall.

Answer (score 0):

For scanning network hosts for service availability I would go with [nmap](https://nmap.org).  It's designed for this sort of job.

```
nmap -pPORT IPADDRESS
```

... will tell you if the specified TCP port is open on the remote host.  UDP scans may be performed with the `-sU` option.  Nmap has many other options for port scanning and analysis that may be worth your time to investigate.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, as there are a bunch of things you cannot deduce remotely. So a complete answer would include information on how to find out what is going on locally on the server.